# Using annotations to define multiple servlets of the same class with different init-params

Tags: java, servlets, init-parameters

I have previously achieved this by using `web.xml` like so:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Test1</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.abc.test.Servlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>propertyKey</param-name>
    <param-value>test1</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Test2</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.abc.test.Servlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>propertyKey</param-name>
    <param-value>test2</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Test1</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Test2</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This means that if I go to `http://server/project/Test1`, the `Servlet` class will get the value `test1` for `propertyKey` and if I go to `http://server/project/Test2`, it will get the value `test2`.

I'm now starting to develop an application for Tomcat 7, so I tried to replicate this using annotations:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Test1", urlPatterns = "/test1", initParams = @WebInitParam(name = "propertyKey", value = "test1"))
@WebServlet(name = "Test2", urlPatterns = "/test2", initParams = @WebInitParam(name = "propertyKey", value = "test2"))
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
// ...
```

This resulted in the error "`Duplicate annotation @WebServlet`".

I also tried putting in arrays of parameters and URL patterns, but they still all apply to the same servlet.

Is it possible to do this, or should I just stick with `web.xml`? Or maybe I'll suck it up and go with `?propertyKey=test1` and `?propertyKey=test2` but I think it's nicer to hide that stuff.

Comment: Why not create two subclasses of a common superclass, differing only by their annotations?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go with XML, you can also register two (or more) instances of your `Servlet` with a `ServletContainerInitializer` and specify different init parameters.

Other than [JB Nizet's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034066/using-annotations-to-define-multiple-servlets-of-the-same-class-with-different-i/29034202#comment46309045_29034066), I don't think you'll find a solution with annotations.

Comment: I'm actually quite happy with the XML, this is more in the interest of using the newer tools available.

Comment: @james Great. `ServletContainerInitializer` _is_ a new tool!